# How to send email with attachment using mysql query

Tags: mysql, email, iis, stored-procedures, email-attachments

Is there a possible way to send email with attachment using mysql? Currently I can send email using mysql but no attachments.
I need to include a docx attachment from hard disk.

I create an eml file and send it to IIS (Inetpub) so that it can fetch the email. This is the working code for email notification:

```
SET @sqlString = CONCAT("SELECT 'To:test@email.com', ",
       "'From: test@email.com', ",
        "'Subject: test', ",
        "'\r\n'",
        "'test'",
        "INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Inetpub/mailroot/Pickup/mail_", CAST(RAND() * (100000 - 1) + 1 AS CHAR(64)), ".eml' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ESCAPED BY ''");

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlString;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

now I need to have an attachment. This is my effort to try it out...

```
   SET @sqlString = CONCAT("SELECT 'To:test@email.com', ",
       "'From: test@email.com', ",
        "'Subject: test', ",
        "'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"C:/text.docx\"',",
    "'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64',",
    "'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"C:/text.docx\"',",
        "'\r\n'",
        "'test'",
        "INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Inetpub/mailroot/Pickup/mail_", CAST(RAND() * (100000 - 1) + 1 AS CHAR(64)), ".eml' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ESCAPED BY ''");

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlString;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

but it only creates a docx file and didn't fetch the correct file. It also erased the body text.

Is there a possible way to attach a file. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Oh good god... don't do this. MySQL has no base64 encoding functions. and you do NOT want to write one yourself. Do this in a client-side app instead. Generating mime emails by hand is also a serious pain.

Comment: @Marc B Thank you for your reply and concern. But I need to schedule the email notification.

Comment: Proper programming languages can build/send emails far far easier than you could ever do it via SQL queries, and be scheduled as well. Again, don't this in the database.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for advice, I think I must really stick to the basics and not abuse mysql hehe. I now use php for emails. While my stored procedure saves the important details of email (to,from,subject,message,path,etc..)

Answer (score 0):

May be insert a record to a table and use a more versatile programming language to periodically check that table for new records to send your email.